# How can I rename functionally in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation, tidyverse

I would like to use `rename_` (or `rename`?) within a function to rename a column from a tibble. For instance, suppose I have `rename(as_tibble(iris)`, petal = Petal.Width)` inside a function like the one below

```
rr <- function(toRename, newName, dt) { 
  rename_(dt, .dots = rlang::expr(list(!! newName = toRename)))
          }
```

where I can pass a dataset to rename, and the elements for the renaming as strings, to that I could call:

```
rr('petal', 'Petal.Width', dt = as_tibble(iris))
```

for renaming `Petal.Width` into `petal`.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sym` with `:=`

```
rr <- function(dt, oldName, newName) { 
 rename(dt, !!rlang::sym(newName) := !! rlang::sym(oldName))
      }

rr(dt = as_tibble(iris), oldName = 'Petal.Width', newName = 'petal') %>%
      head(., 2)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length petal Species
#         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl> <fctr> 
#1         5.10        3.50         1.40 0.200 setosa 
#2         4.90        3.00         1.40 0.200 setosa
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it a bit more readable and intuitive, we can use embracing
:

```
rr <- function(dt, oldName, newName) { 
 rename(dt, rename({{ newName }} := {{ oldName }})
      }
```

See [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) for more information on programming using dplyr verbs.